# grastate.dat with seqno -1 on a healthy cluster. Why?

Tags: linux, mariadb, clustering, galera

We use those versions:

```
# rpm -qa | egrep '(galera|maria)'
mariadb-libs-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64
mariadb-galera-common-5.5.40-6.el7ost.x86_64
mariadb-galera-server-5.5.40-6.el7ost.x86_64
mariadb-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64
galera-25.3.5-6.el7ost.x86_64
```

that's our grastate.dat

```
# cat /var/lib/mysql/data/grastate.dat
# GALERA saved state
version: 2.1
uuid:    e7ead849-f2a3-11e4-bfda-7f651f709ee3
seqno:   -1
cert_index:
```

The `seqno:   -1`  looks fishy. On other clusters there is a number. I don't know why. According to docs this seems "crashed". The -1 is after outage. But this cluster is healthy.

modify time is long ago

```
# stat /var/lib/mysql/data/grastate.dat
  File: â/var/lib/mysql/data/grastate.datâ
  Size: 104             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd09h/64777d    Inode: 108         Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: ( 1000/   mysql)   Gid: ( 1000/   mysql)
Context: system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0
Access: 2015-07-29 14:51:25.170699518 +0200
Modify: 2015-06-02 11:50:21.564360655 +0200
Change: 2015-06-02 11:50:21.564360655 +0200
 Birth: -
```

from logs (no errors only info and warnings):

```
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'galera_cluster'
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Starting new group from scratch: e7ead849-f2a3-11e4-bfda-7f651f709ee3
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: e7eae37d-f2a3-11e4-a76e-6e8297197928
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: e7eae37d-f2a3-11e4-a76e-6e8297197928
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: e7eae37d-f2a3-11e4-a76e-6e8297197928 from 0 (hostname.domain)
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
        version    = 3,
        component  = PRIMARY,
        conf_id    = 0,
        members    = 1/1 (joined/total),
        act_id     = 0,
        last_appl. = -1,
        protocols  = 0/5/3 (gcs/repl/appl),
        group UUID = e7ead849-f2a3-11e4-bfda-7f651f709ee3
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [16, 16]
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Restored state OPEN -> JOINED (0)
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (hostname.domain) synced with group.
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 0)
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: e7ead849-f2a3-11e4-bfda-7f651f709ee3:0, view# 1: Primary, number of nodes: 1, my index: 0, protocol version 3
150504 23:24:11 [Note] WSREP: SST complete, seqno: 0
150504 23:24:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150504 23:24:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150504 23:24:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
150504 23:24:11 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
```

status

```
> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep%';
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                    |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | e7ead849-f2a3-11e4-bfda-7f651f709ee3                     |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 5                                                        |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 15995162                                                 |
| wsrep_replicated             | 15995162                                                 |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 7552231516                                               |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 73658848                                                 |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 957160108                                                |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 5571381040                                               |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_received               | 127686                                                   |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 1023418                                                  |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 15994368                                                 |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 8                                                        |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000063                                                 |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.002921                                                 |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 15719139                                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 1.046783                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.008655                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.009090                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                                 |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.000440                                                 |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                        |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                                   |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 57                                                       |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.011088                                                 |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 192.168.221.22:3306,192.168.211.20:3306,192.168.210.21:3306 |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 6                                                        |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                        |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | e7ead849-f2a3-11e4-bfda-7f651f709ee3                     |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                                  |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                       |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                        |
| wsrep_local_index            | 1                                                        |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                   |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                        |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 3.5(rXXXX)                                               |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                       |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                        |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
48 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `grastate.dat` with a sequence number of -1 is fine on a running node.

When the cluster stops cleanly, the sequence number will be set to a value on each node. You'll then have to bootstrap the cluster from the node which has the most advanced seqno.

Answer (score 0):

second with this
[link](https://severalnines.com/blog/updated-how-bootstrap-mysql-or-mariadb-galera-cluster),
an error occurred when the nodes were disconnected without order, as in my cluster, my main node is not connecting anymore.
erro of mysql:

> [ERROR] WSREP: It may not be safe to bootstrap the cluster from this node. It was not the last one to leave the cluster and may not contain all the updates. To force cluster bootstrap with this node, edit the grastate.dat file manually and set safe_to_bootstrap to 1 .

so I decided to change `/var/lib/mysql/grastate.dat`

> safe_to_bootstrap: 1