# The right way of starting up a Galera Cluster

Tags: mariadb, clustering, galera

I am confused about the bootstrap process of MariaDB Galera Cluster.

Let's say we have 3 nodes of a MariaDB Galera Cluster, working and functioning normally on CentOS6/7. However, at some point we have (doesn't matter by what reason) to stop all 3 nodes and then start up the cluster. We are stopping the nodes 1 by 1 normally and cleanly. In order to start up the cluster, I go and check out *grastate.dat* and see which node is with most current data. I bootstrap this node first.

What is unclear to me is how the bootstrap is done exactly for CentOS 6 and 7. The 2nd and 3rd node can be started with `systemctl start mysql`. How do we start the first node? Do we use `service mysql start --bootstrap` on the first node with most current data? I read that for CentOS 7 it's `systemctl start mysql@bootstrap.service`. What is the procedure of boostrapping the first node of the cluster after we stopped all 3 nodes normally?

PS: Related to this, with some more details, is the post by [dr01](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/61978/dr01):
[grastate.dat with seqno -1 on a healthy cluster. Why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108437/grastate-dat-with-seqno-1-on-a-healthy-cluster-why)

Answer (score 3):

At MariaDB 10.1 where Galera included you need to start first node with key `--wsrep-new-cluster`

e.g.
`/etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster`

All other nodes starts as usually:

`/etc/init.d/mysql start`

To determine which node needs to be bootstrapped, compare the `wsrep_last_committed` value on all DB nodes:

```
KVM-1> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';
+----------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name        | Value       |
+----------------------+-------------+
| wsrep_last_committed | 21568       |
...
| wsrep_cluster_status | non-Primary |
+----------------------+-------------+

KVM-2> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';
+----------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name        | Value       |
+----------------------+-------------+
| wsrep_last_committed |  1359       |
...
| wsrep_cluster_status | non-Primary |
+----------------------+-------------+



KVM-3> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';
+----------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name        | Value       |
+----------------------+-------------+
| wsrep_last_committed |   537       |
...
| wsrep_cluster_status | non-Primary |
+----------------------+-------------+
```

KVM-1 has the most up-to-date data. In this case, all Galera nodes are already started, so you don’t necessarily need to bootstrap the cluster again. We just need to promote KVM-1 to be a Primary Component:

```
KVM-1> SET GLOBAL wsrep_provider_options="pc.bootstrap=1";
```

The remaining nodes will then reconnect to the Primary Component (KVM-1) and resyncing back data based on this node.

Comment: Roman, first thank you for your reply. But with --wsrep-new-cluster it will create a new cluster right? Is this the normal behavior - to create a new cluster if all nodes were stopped and then started? Will this reflect somehow on the databases/schemas and data?

Comment: Which replication do you use: Master-Slave or Master-Master? This newer bootstrapping method was enabled by the `--wsrep-new-cluster `command-line option. [MariaDB Docs](https://mariadb.com/blog/mariadb-galera-cluster-quirk-bootstrapping). As for me, I use 3 nodes with master-master replication, and when all of the nodes are down, I starts one of the stable nodes with this key and other nodes as usual.

Comment: Master-Master, 3 nodes. I am just confused if by any chance I stopped normally the 3 nodes, how to boot the primary one (I'll identified that from the seq found in grastate.dat). Is it fine to create a new cluster when I have all 3 nodes stopped? Because --wsrep-new-cluster will do exactly this. Will I lose or messed the data/schemas of the old cluster?

Comment: I use 3 nodes with master-master too. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133668/galera-wont-start/133686#133686

Comment: Did you stop all nodes in your case or that was the first initial run of the cluster? In my case I have wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://node1,node2,node3" in all 3 nodes. I don't get again the start up procedure.

Comment: Yes, i initialized servers crush with hard-reset. At **10.1** i got error with `gcomm://node1,node2,node3`.  At 10.0 i used config as you and all works. Check answer, i edited it.

Comment: I don't have the nodes running. I am trying to explain you that I have all the 3 nodes in a stopped state. I have identified the node with most current position so I know which node to bootstrap. How I bootstrap this node? Using --wsrep-new-cluster will create a new cluster so what will happened with my old schemas/data? Will I lose them? Is the normal behavior if you have the 3 nodes stop to create a new cluster (you are not using the old cluster which was running)?

Comment: You start it with `/etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster` on main node and other as usually. All as i can say at first time) I just tested it 5 minutes ago. U can check it at test server yourself.